# Can I write code like this? A novice in C language

Tags: c, gcc

What is the standard of practice?

Will this overflow memory?

I want to get a FileDescriptor.

```c
int fd = fileno(fopen("/path", "w+"));
close(fd);

//or

FILE * fp = fopen("...");
int fd = fileno(fd);

fclose(fp);
```

For some reason, I have to use "fopen"

Comment: Statements in C are terminated by semicolons.

Comment: Either example is fine (once you take care of the syntax errors, anyway).  If you use the `FILE *` API exclusively you'll get better portability (e.g. under Windows you can't use `int` as a file-descriptor, but `FILE *` will work just about everywhere)

Comment: Former will leak the `FILE*` object even though the file descriptor is closed. If you're using `close`, just use `open`.

Comment: I may know. 

Thank you

Comment: @Passerby: Some of them are, some are not.

Comment: I also wouldn't use `fileno(fopen("/path", "w+"))` for the simple reason that you don't get an opportunity to verify that `fopen` succeeded and returned a valid `FILE *`. Better that it's two separate calls.

Comment: I have executed "chmod 0777 /path/to" before

If the path is determined to exist, I don't think it is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to use matching open and close functions. This is true of files and memory and anything else that gives you a magic value/pointer/whatever.

Hence, use fopen() with fclose().
Use open() with close().
Use malloc() with free().
Etc.

If you need to access the underlying file descriptor / file handle / whatever, that is fine, but don’t break the abstraction by then treating the curated resource as if it were the curator.

Answer (score 0):

With option 1, if there is any write activity on the file stream between when the file is opened and the file descriptor is closed, then that activity is likely to be buffered and will not be flushed.  However, as written, you've lost the file stream (you don't even check that the `fopen()` succeeded — dangerous!), so there can't be any activity on the stream.  However, the resources allocated for the stream are lost, and cleanup work at the end of the program will fail to close the file descriptor for that stream because it was closed separately (but there's no way for that failure to be reported).  All of that amounts to "Not a Good Idea".

With option 2, you cannot use the file descriptor after `fclose(fp)` because it will have been closed by `fclose()`.  Again, you have to be careful if you mix actions on the file stream with actions on the file descriptor.  It is still not a very good idea.

Unless you have very compelling reasons to do otherwise, either use `fopen()` and `fclose()` — and other file stream functions — to manipulate the file, or use `open()` and `close()` — and other file descriptor functions — to manipulate the file.  Do not try to mix'n'match.  Functions such as `fileno()` and `fdopen()` exist to cross the file stream/file descriptor boundary for good reasons, but you should be cautious about using them.